# Is there a way to iteratively rotate instances in Geometry Nodes? Ideally looking something like "Transform Instances"

Tags: geometry-nodes

Learning Geometry Nodes, spent a few hours searching and can't find the equivalent of "Transform Instances" - I want to iteratively rotate my instances, I see "Translate Instances" which lets me move them around (with math+combine+translate) but I want to spin them - is there a node or node combo for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no combined *Transform Instances*, but all three transform operations are available as separate nodes—*Translate Instances, Rotate Instances*, and *Scale Instances*.

[image]

Comment: wow - not sure how I missed that, thanks!

Comment: @Kevin Easy to miss things when you're new :) If that was what you're looking for can you mark it as accepted, please? The check mark right beneath the upvote/downvote arrows. Thanks.